# How do you assign categories to Work Item Types within Azure DevOps 2019 using an Inheritance Process Model?

Tags: azure-devops, testcase, test-suite, azure-rm-template, test-plan

What I want is to create a work item type under the Test Case category (Microsoft.TestCaseCategory). The reason for this is to create a work item which has the test steps built in as a group already. This way, a new work item can be created in the usual manner and once ready, you should be able to create a query-based test suite and pull all the items in that you want to add test steps. The query would be something like this

- Work Item Type | In Group | Microsoft.TestCaseCategory
- AND Work Item Type | = | "New WIT name"
- AND Status | = | Ready For Test

I have searched all available resources online for Azure DevOps. This seems possible but I believe the main point that is stopping me is that my organization is using an Inheritance Process Model and not Hosted XML/On-premises XML Model. Is there any possible workaround to this?

If not, how would I go about changing to a Hosted/On-premises XML Model since that is also information I could not clearly find.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I go about changing to a Hosted/On-premises XML Model

For this issue , when you create a project collection, you'll need to choose between `XML`  and `Inheritance`, as shown in the following dialog. And the choice you make is not **reversible**. Once the collection is created, you'll only be able to customize work tracking objects using the model selected. Also, there is no way to migrate existing project collections that use the On-premises XML process model to the Inheritance process model. You can refer to the `Important` part of this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?view=azure-devops-2019#choose-the-process-model-for-your-project-collection).

[image]

So according to your actual situation, you can only create new work item type under Inheritance process.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. This is useful information and I appreciate the link as well since I clearly missed this during my fact finding mission. I will approach the system admin to see if we can change the Process since the Categories feature is something which is key. Fortunately, we are still in the early stages of using the system so I believe we could manual enter a lot of the current data within the new process. The loss of audit information may be the showstopper though. Thanks again for your thoughts

Comment: Glad to help you , if this is helpful to you, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. Have a nice day:)